# Many-to-many collection mapping in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

My application is a multi-user podcast aggregator, using NHibernate 2.1 (and .NET 4.0 if that changes anything).  I'm also a complete NHibernate n00b.

Details of each podcast are only stored once, and Users subscribe to podcasts, so there is a many-to-many mapping between podcasts and users which I have mapped in my database with a Subscriptions table:

```
Subscriptions(UserId, FeedId)
```

I also have a UserFeedItems table which stores per-user-per-item information:

```
UserFeedItems(UserId, FeedItemId, IsNew, ListenCount, etc.)
```

My object model is a bit different:

```
class Podcast {
    IList<PodcastFeedItem> FeedItems { get; set; }
    bool HasNew {
        get {
            // return true if any of the FeedItems are new
        }
    }
}

class PodcastFeedItem {
    bool IsNew { get; set; }
}

class User {
    IList<PodcastFeed> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

What mappings do I need in NHibernate to correctly map the relational model to the object model?  Have I gone to far by defining those "link" tables listed above?  Ordering may be important here, as obviously I need to keep the feeds organised in descending chronological order.

I've read through [the documentation on collection mapping](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/collections.html), but I'm struggling to fit the examples to my own scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a classic Many-to-Many where a Podcast can have many subscribers and a subscriber can subscribe to many podcasts.  You map it like this:

```
<class name="App.Core.Domain.User, App.Core" table="users">
    <set name="SubscribedPodcasts" table="subscriptions" inverse="false" cascade="all">
      <key column="userid"/>
      <many-to-many class="App.Core.Domain.Podcasts, App.Core" column="podcastid"/>
    </set>
</class>


<class name="App.Core.Domain.Podcast, App.Core" table="podcasts">
    <set name="SubscribedUsers" table="subscriptions" inverse="false" cascade="all">
      <key column="podcastid"/>
      <many-to-many class="App.Core.Domain.User, App.Core" column="userid"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

If you really want to store the index in the database rather than having NH order the results (I have never had to do this as its better to order by a column and have NH provide your indexes).  then add

```
<index-many-to-many
        column="column_name"                
        class="ClassName"                   
/>
```

To the mapping

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed answer; unfortunately I'm still waiting for a spare moment to test this out.

Comment: A couple of questions:
  1. Why a set over a bag?
  2. Should the class name be the same in both the many-to-many tags?  Not one Podcasts, one Users?  (I'm not sure which way around it should be, if so).

Comment: There is an error in the above mapping, the second many-to-many shoud be class Users - sorry about that I will update the answer.

Comment: Re:Set/bag....In the .NET collections hierarchy there isn't a set implementation, so .NET users tend not to use it.  NHibernate comes with an implementation of a Set from Iesi.Collections.  The key thing to know about a Set is that each object can only exist once, however in a bag, e.g. IList the same object can exist more than once.  For a more detailed description see:

http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/06/12/mapping-collections-in-nhibernate-part-1.aspx

and you'll see that in theoretical terms, a set is actually the correct Collection type to use in this instance.

Comment: In practical terms though, .Net users tend to overuse bags/Lists for everything and, as long as you check the collection beforehand to ensure that the item doesn't actually exist its ok. With a Set, you can call Add() without checking and the object will be added if it doesn't exist and will be added if it does.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the lookup table. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319178/nhibernate-mapping-of-lookup-collection-if-that-makes-any-sense) provides the details on how to perform a many to many in NHibernate

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The answer you link to implies I don't need a class for my lookup table (which I don't have, and wasn't expecting to need).  However, the example mapping in the other answer (from the OP) still uses the lookup table.  Is that right?

Comment: Correct, you don't need to define the class, but you still need to map the relationship through the table in the database